# Parallels - MacOS host & guest - How to allow the bypassing of certain shortcuts to host os

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, parallels

I am trying out parallels now and wondering if it is possible to **allow** the **guest** **os** to **bypass** certain **shortcuts** to the **host**?

That way i could allow most of them to be the same on the host, but some, like launching a program only the host has, can be bypassed.

It has a send macOS system shortcuts but with only **Auto**, **Always**, **Never**.

Seems like **Auto** should be this thing, but I can't figure out a way to say what would be fit not "Always" or "Never" conditions.

Might be the **Keyboard Menu** but that is only for internal Parallels stuff. Rather I would like basically that, but to allow the shortcut to bypass to **Never** basically for certain shortcuts.

Feels essential and should not be too difficult to implement. Maybe as a plugin already provides this? **Config file**?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is possible per virtual machines, you can choose eache shortcut by checking the ON/OFF checkbox for each one that you want to enable and pass to the guest. You can also create custom shortcuts. And also create templates.

I am posting a picture here, showing those shortcuts options on Parallels Preferences.

[Parallels Guest shortcuts preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzG9Y.png)

Comment: yes, I know that's possible. But I want to pass ALL of them, excluding two or three. There is a lot of shortcuts. I can't add all of them to be passed to the guest. Rather everything should go to the guest, but a couple. Understand?

Comment: Hmm, now I understood. You need something like "negation". Everything goes except what you determine. I will check parallels options again to certify is this can work this way. I will post a reply here later. Thank you for clarifying.